# AWS web application - rough estimate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to make a rough estimate to how much it would cost per hour when running a web application within AWS. I understand that this depends on the type of web application, network capacity, throughput etc. Very roughly, how many concurrent sessions can a medium or large server manage? Let's say that the number of clients is at any time 8000 - roughly, what would that cost?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is difficult to answer because it is too broad -- it depends upon what your application does, the level of performance required, how you store your data, etc. Please provide additional details of your application, configuration, behaviour, etc to assist us in providing you with a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can answer your question asked like that. A rough estimate can be between 10 and 10k USD. What I suggest is to use the AWS calculator to calculate your estimate. Add some EC2 machines, and transfer out, and you should see some kind of estimate.

https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html